Attempting to enable synchronous scrolling in excel by VBA script
Attempting to enable synchronous scrolling in excel by VBA script. After script sorts by name, & compares two sheets, colors discrepancies, resorts by newest date then displays both sheets side by side.
I checked command codes for tool bars as described in Are the command codes for ExecuteMso documented?
I tried code
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("WindowSideBySideSynchronousScrolling")
read out error "run-time error '5' invalid procedure call or argument
I tried code
ActiveWindow.SyncedScrolling = True
read out error 'run-time error '438'object doesn't support this property or method
I noticed to use the tool bar manually I must go to view tab - window section and click view side by side then synchronous scrolling button will enable for clicking
so I then attempted to combine the code above to enable side by side view then synchronous scrolling. the code I attempted before synchronous scrolling is:
1
ActiveWindow.ViewSideBySideWith = Windows(2)
2
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ViewSideBySide")
im not sure why im getting the errors any assistance is greatly appreciated. all code code works for me untill I add scrolling feature. complete code is below if needed. Thanks
Complete code:
Sub SortCompareSortByDateAndViewSideBySide()
    ' Sort sheet "New" by column 1 A-Z
    With Sheets("New")
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    
    ' Sort sheet "New (2)" by column 1 A-Z
    With Sheets("New (2)")
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    
    ' Compare column 4 of sheet "New" and "New (2)"
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowNew As Long
    Dim lastRowNew2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set wsNew = Sheets("New")
    Set wsNew2 = Sheets("New (2)")
    
    lastRowNew = wsNew.Cells(wsNew.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowNew2 = wsNew2.Cells(wsNew2.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Ensure both sheets have the same number of rows in column 4 for comparison
    If lastRowNew <> lastRowNew2 Then
        MsgBox "The number of rows in column 4 of both sheets is not the same."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For i = 2 To lastRowNew ' Assuming there is a header row
        If wsNew.Cells(i, 4).Value = wsNew2.Cells(i, 4).Value Then
            wsNew.Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green
            wsNew2.Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' Green
        Else
            wsNew.Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange
            wsNew2.Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Sort sheet "New" by column 5 (Date) newest to oldest
    With wsNew
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("E1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    
    ' Sort sheet "New (2)" by column 5 (Date) newest to oldest
    With wsNew2
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("E1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    
    ' Change the window view to split side by side vertically
    If Windows.Count = 1 Then
        ActiveWindow.NewWindow
    End If
    
    ' Arrange windows vertically
    Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical
    
    ' Ensure sheet "New" is open in the first window and sheet "New (2)" is open in the second window
    Windows(1).Activate
    Sheets("New").Activate
    Windows(2).Activate
    Sheets("New (2)").Activate
    
    ' Enable view side by side and synchronized scrolling
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ViewSideBySide")
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("WindowViewSideBySideSynchronousScrolling")
End Sub


Maybe try:
Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical
Windows("New").Activate
Windows.CompareSideBySideWith "New (2)"

